# Loop through excel and store data in a dictionary python

Tags: python, loops, openpyxl

Im trying to loop through an excel sheet and store specific data in a dictionary. I have an excel sheet that has only one column. in the column is carriers names and dates they took a load from me with some miscellaneous data. i want to search the column for the carriers name and save that to a dictionary. then there will be dates below that, that signal when they took a load. I want to count the cells that have dates in them until it gets to the next carrier. I then want to save the load count(cells with dates) in the dictionary with the corresponding carrier name. I have gotten the carrier name to save in the dictionary but i dont know how to continue the loop and count the cells with dates and store that value in 'loads': loadnumber. then to continue on with the loop.

```
    # Function to add new entries to the dictionary
    def add_entry(dictionary, key, value):
        dictionary[key] = value

    import openpyxl
    from datetime import datetime


    # Load the Excel workbook
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'path to carrier2.xlsx')
    sheet = workbook.active  # Assuming you want to work with the active sheet

    # Dictionary to store data
    data_dict = {}

    # Specify the starting row and the number of rows to iterate through
    start_row = 2
    num_rows = sheet.max_row - start_row + 1

    # Loop through rows starting from the specified row
    for i, row in enumerate(sheet.iter_rows(min_row=start_row, max_col=1, max_row=start_row + num_rows -  1), start=start_row):
        cell_value = row[0].value
        if cell_value == "Carrier":
            # Get the value one row above
            value_above = sheet.cell(row=row[0].row - 1, column=1).value
            if value_above:
        
                add_entry(data_dict, i, {'name': value_above, 'loads': 0})



    # Print the dictionary with the saved data
    print(data_dict)

    # Close the workbook
    workbook.close()
```

excel sheet looks like this

[image]

Comment: Why are you using `i` as the dictionary key? Wouldn't it be better to use the carrier name as the key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work fine: the updated code now properly counts the loads based on datetime values

```
import openpyxl
from datetime import datetime

file_path = 'p6OFI.xlsx'
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path)
sheet = workbook.active

start_row = 2
num_rows = sheet.max_row - start_row + 1
current_carrier = None
data = {}

for i, row in enumerate(sheet.iter_rows(min_row=start_row, max_col=1, max_row=start_row + num_rows -  1), start=start_row):
    cell_value = row[0].value
    if cell_value == "Carrier":
        carrier_loads = 0
        current_carrier = sheet.cell(row=row[0].row - 1, column=1).value
    elif isinstance(cell_value, datetime):
        carrier_loads +=1
        data[current_carrier] = carrier_loads
workbook.close()

for carrier, load_count in data.items():
    print(f"Carrier: {carrier} | Load Count: {load_count}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `cell_value.isnumeric()` to match the lines with load numbers. When this matches, add 1 to the load counter.

```
    for i, row in enumerate(sheet.iter_rows(min_row=start_row, max_col=1, max_row=start_row + num_rows -  1), start=start_row):
        cell_value = row[0].value
        if cell_value == "Carrier":
            # Get the value one row above
            value_above = sheet.cell(row=row[0].row - 1, column=1).value
            if value_above:
                current_carrier = {'name': value_above, 'loads': 0}
                add_entry(data_dict, i, current_carrier)
        elif cell_value.isnumeric():
            # Add the load to the current carrier
            current_carrier['loads'] += 1
```